# How do I eliminate the 'TypeError: open() missing required argument 'flags' (pos 2)' error?

Tags: python, typeerror

I have a directory within which I have files that I would like to open and read in. I have tried a lot of different modifications but I keep getting the same error:'
TypeError: open() missing required argument 'flags' (pos 2)'. I am not entirely sure of what it is that needs to be changed here or what is wrong to begin with.

````
    if filename.endswith('.txt'):
      with open(os.path.join('/content/drive/MyDrive/shrink_10bp', filename)) as f:
        content = f.read()```

```for filepath in glob.glob(os.path.join('/content/drive/MyDrive/shrink_10bp', '*.txt')):
    with open(filepath) as f:
        content = f.read()```
````

Comment: You haven't opened the file with any mode,  `with open(filename, 'r') as f:` for example

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Comment: @will-hedges that is not responsible for the problem. The problem is not reproducible with the code shown, but can easily be reproduced if the built-in `open` is replaced with `os.open`.